# Differential equation using high school methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0)=1$.
If

$$f'(x)\sqrt{x^2+1}=f(x), \;\; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

holds, then find $f$.

*I want to solve the D.E using high school methods not invoking already formulas but I find it extremely difficult.*

I multiplied the equation by $2x$ , then brought that $2xf(x)$ at the other side , divided by $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ and later I was able to get to:

$$2xf'(x)-\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)'f(x)=0$$

I don't know how to continue. Perhaps this was not the right path to go down. Any hints? I would not like a solution, just hints.

Comment: Your method is correct, the only error is that $(\sqrt{x^2+1})'=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$. There is a factor $1/2$ in the derivative of the square root. Use $$(\sqrt{x^2+1}^k)'=k·x·\sqrt{x^2+1}^{k-2}$$ to identify $k=-1$ to get the correct form of the product or quotient rule.

Comment: Oups... I forgot about that.

Comment: @LutzL That was my goal to get into a quotient rule or product one.. but I cannot fix the other one.. that $2x$ is bothering me.

So, after your note (which is correct) the OD comes to the form:

$$2xf'(x)-2(\sqrt{x^2+1})'f(x)=0$$

Then how can I proceed? Any more hints? I already have a solution by Alex under high school methods.. but I want to see if this idea can continue... (i'm confident it goes further.. but I cannot see it)

Comment: This only works with the rather artificial method of subtracting $x·f'(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}·f(x)$ from the original equation leading to $(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)·f(x)=C$ and using binomial formulas $(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)^{-1}=(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)$.

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow you.. Substract what?

Comment: One equation from the other. $$\sqrt{x^2+1}·f'(x)-x⋅f′(x)=f(x)-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}·f(x)$$ and in this form the product rule works.

Comment: Yes @LutzL got it now... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by writing $g(x) = \ln f(x)$. It should fall under high-school method".

Then compute $g'(x)$ ... (btw because $f(0)=1$ you know that $g$ is defined at least on a neighborhood of $0$).

Comment: How do you know that $f$ is positive and you insert it into an $\ln $?

Comment: This way the D.E falls easily and yes it falls under high-school method. But i have an objection why you can still insert $f$ into an $\ln $ since you know nothing about $f$ being positive. Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: Well as I said, since $f(0)=1$ and $f$ is $C^1$ (at least, given the equation), $f > 0$ on a non-empty open set around $0$. So $g$ is defined at least "somewhere".

Comment: yes, I should have mentioned that $f$ is differentiable... Sorry. Thank you!

Comment: well that is kinda assumed from a solution to a pde. Also in this case, note that for $x>0$, you can "see from the equation" that $f'(x)>0$, so since $f(0)>0$, $f(x) \ge f(0) > 0$.

Comment: @Tolaso: also don't forget to accept the answer if you got what you were looking for

Comment: It is a frequent error to forget the absolute value in the anti-derivative of $1/x$. Set $g(x)=\ln|f(x)|$ and you only have to care about $f(x)=0$, which can be excluded as the constant solution.

Comment: @AlexHalm How can I see from the equation that for $x>0$ $f'(x)>0$. And for $x<0$ what's happening? I'll probably accept your answer but I have to run it through my mind a little more.

Comment: You can't. Negative solutions are completely acceptable. Except that the initial condition and the constant solution $0$ forces the sign for your IVP to stay positive.

Comment: What about if I considered $g(x)=\ln |f(x)|$ differentiate and then use the equation given get something for $x\neq 0$. Then the only problem would be zero.. but if $x=0$ then $f'(0)=1>0$ so we have no problem here, but still something does suit me well... when I differntiate I get $f(x)$ in the denominator.. and I'm not sure there are no roots for $x\neq 0$.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure there's a "high-school level" way of showing that $f>0$, usually pde existence, unicity and maximal domain of validity are handled by (slightly) more advanced theorems. You could rebuild all this "by hand" in this particular case, but I'm not sure it's worth the pain.

Comment: @AlexHalm: What is this pde you are speaking about? p - partial, o - ordinary, thus ODE.

Comment: @LutzL: thanks, pavlovian typing...

Answer (score 3):

You can be inspired by the identity $\sqrt{\sinh^2t+1}=\cosh t$, which calls for the change of variable $x=\sinh t$.

Then by the chain rule,

$$\frac{df(x)}{dx}\sqrt{x^2+1}=\frac{df(\sinh t)}{d\sinh t}\cosh t=\frac{df(\sinh t)}{\cosh t\,dt}\cosh t=\frac{df(\sinh t)}{dt}=f(\sinh t).$$

The solution of this familiar equation is

$$f(\sinh t)=Ce^t$$
or
$$f(x)=Ce^{\text{arsinh }x}=C(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}).$$

Comment: I really like this one, but unfortunately hyperbolic function don't fall under high school mathematics. (+1) anyway.